# How can complex type property be used as identifier in Entity Framework AddOrUpdate method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

In my application I have a model `User`

```
public class User
{
    private ICollection<User> friends;
    private ICollection<Album> albums;

    public User()
    {
        this.albums = new HashSet<Album>();
        this.friends = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }

    public int BornTownId { get; set; }

    public Town BornTown { get; set; }


    public int CurrentLivingTownId { get; set; }

    public Town CurrentLivingTown { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends
    {
        get
        {
            return this.friends;
        }
        set
        {
            this.friends = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums
    {
        get
        {
            return this.albums;
        }
        set
        {
            this.albums = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here,  `UserInfo` is a complex type which looks like this:

```
[ComplexType]
public class UserInfo
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [Column("FirstName",TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [MinLength(2)]
    [Column("LastName", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [MinLength(4)]
    [Column("Username", TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(6)]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column("Password", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [PasswordValidation]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Email", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailValidation]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("RegisteredOn")]
    public DateTime RegisteredOn { get; set; }

    [Column("LastTimeLoggedIn")]
    public DateTime LastTimeLoggedIn { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 120)]
    [Column("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Column("IsDeleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to seed data for the Users table with `context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.UserInfo.Username, user);`, 
I get the following error message:

```
Message=The properties expression 'u => u.UserInfo.Username' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'.
```

My question(which is as complex as the target of the problem) is: 
What is the correct syntactic way to use `u.UserInfo.Username` as identifier in AddOrUpdate, should I add any tag to `UserInfo` class or property or make changes with the `FluentApi` and is what I am trying to do a proper way to use AddOrUpdate.

I realize that I can take `Username` out of UserInfo and put it directly in `User` but I am aiming for more "broad" solution.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious if you do not do AddorUpdate, is EF creating columns for your complex type's properties?

Comment: @Coding Yoshi EF adds columns the first time I use AddOrUpdate in this way but does not seed the values, it throws exception in subsequent seeds . When i use AddOrUpdate without identifier it also seeds the table with the provided values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i could think of without transferring `Username` to `User` is to check first if a `user` with given `UserInfo.Username` exists in the `Users` `DbSet`:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserInfo.Username == username)
                               ?? new User
                               {
                                   UserInfo = new UserInfo()
                                   {
                                       FirstName = firstName,
                                       LastName = lastName,
                                       Username = username,
                                       Password = password,
                                       Email = email,
                                       RegisteredOn = registeredOnDate.AddDays(2),
                                       LastTimeLoggedIn = lastDateLoggedOn.AddDays(10),
                                       IsDeleted = isDeleted
                                   }
                               };
```

Then use `AddOrUpdate` with the `params TEntity[] entities`  overload, which does not employ the "culprit" `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<User, object>> expression` that leads to the InvalidOperationException.

```
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);
```

`EF` updates the values correctly and so this works.
I am still sad that while you can make queries with complex type you can not use complex type in `AddOrUpdate` extension method to update database data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'll get this to work is by moving `UserName` property out to User class, as you said.

`AddOrUpdate` requires that you pass either a simple property of the target type in order to execute properly or an anonymous object in case that you  want to match your entities using more than one property, but it'll complain if you pass any other kind of expression function to it.

So, I'll recommend you to declare you `Username` property on the User class.

Additional advice: remember to always initialize your complex types:

```
public class User
{
    private ICollection<User> friends;
    private ICollection<Album> albums;

    public User()
    {
        this.albums = new HashSet<Album>();
        this.friends = new HashSet<User>();

        //Good practice: always initialize your complex type properties
        UserInfo = new UserInfo();
    }

    //the rest of your class members here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know complex types are required but as i have required properties inside UserInfo I will get ArgumentNullException anyway.